# Complex return in Ternary Operator?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ternary-operator

I am trying to return a specifically styled date after checking the state of an element but struggling with the exact way to write this. 
I have this code for a textview in my XML:

```
android:text='@{String.format(item.status.toLowerCase().contains("check") ?  ("Scheduled for %s", item.ScheduledDate) : ("Published on %s", item.PublishedDate))}'
```

but it is expecting a **+<>=-** rather than the **,**

Can someone please help me encapsulate this properly?

Comment: You can not do it from xml...

Comment: Oh okay thanks maybe I will just add the extra text in with my getter then?

Comment: Yes. that can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to do that from within whichever Java class sets the content view to the xml file in question.

Like so:

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    String text = (item.status.toLowerCase().contains("check") ? String.format("Scheduled for %1$s", item.ScheduledDate) : String.format("Published on %1$s", item.PublishedDate);
    tv.setText(text);
```